# why are multiple line numbers mapped to the same starting address in .debug_line?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, dwarf, debug-information

It's ./drivers/net/virtio_net.c in linux kernel 6.0.0 and compiled to virtio_net.o with optimization -O2 and debuginfo(dwarf4). The  `readelf --debug-dump=decodedline drivers/net/virtio_net.o` shows:

```
drivers/net/virtio_net.c:
virtio_net.c                                2070                0x55       5       x
virtio_net.c                                2082                0x55       6
virtio_net.c                                2072                0x63
virtio_net.c                                2070                0x6a
virtio_net.c                                2071                0x71               x
virtio_net.c                                2071                0x71       1
virtio_net.c                                2072                0x78               x
virtio_net.c                                2073                0x78       1       x
virtio_net.c                                2073                0x78       2
```

we can see line 2070 and 2082 are mapped to the same address 0x55

and the .c:

```
for (i = 0; i < vi->max_queue_pairs; i++) {
    u64 tpackets, tbytes, terrors, rpackets, rbytes, rdrops;
    struct receive_queue *rq = &vi->rq[i];
    struct send_queue *sq = &vi->sq[i];

    do {
        start = u64_stats_fetch_begin_irq(&sq->stats.syncp);
        tpackets = sq->stats.packets;  //line: 2070
        tbytes   = sq->stats.bytes;
        terrors  = sq->stats.tx_timeouts;
    } while (u64_stats_fetch_retry_irq(&sq->stats.syncp, start));

    do {
        start = u64_stats_fetch_begin_irq(&rq->stats.syncp);
        rpackets = rq->stats.packets;
        rbytes   = rq->stats.bytes;
        rdrops   = rq->stats.drops;
    } while (u64_stats_fetch_retry_irq(&rq->stats.syncp, start));

    tot->rx_packets += rpackets;  //line: 2082
    tot->tx_packets += tpackets;
    tot->rx_bytes   += rbytes;
    tot->tx_bytes   += tbytes;
    tot->rx_dropped += rdrops;
    tot->tx_errors  += terrors;
}
```

for objdump, when disassembling it with -l (show lines), it generates:

```
/root/linux-master/drivers/net/virtio_net.c:2082
      55:   48 03 98 a0 01 00 00    add    0x1a0(%rax),%rbx
      5c:   49 81 c4 58 04 00 00    add    $0x458,%r12
/root/linux-master/drivers/net/virtio_net.c:2072
      63:   4c 8b b5 b8 02 00 00    mov    0x2b8(%rbp),%r14
/root/linux-master/drivers/net/virtio_net.c:2070
      6a:   4c 8b bd 90 02 00 00    mov    0x290(%rbp),%r15
/root/linux-master/drivers/net/virtio_net.c:2071
      71:   4c 8b ad 98 02 00 00    mov    0x298(%rbp),%r13
/root/linux-master/drivers/net/virtio_net.c:2079
      78:   48 8b a8 b0 01 00 00    mov    0x1b0(%rax),%rbp
/root/linux-master/drivers/net/virtio_net.c:2072
      7f:   4c 89 34 24             mov    %r14,(%rsp)
```

it seems objdump think the instruction at address 0x55 should be corresponded with line 2082. I'm confused about it's approach.

And I'd like to know when facing this situation ( one instrucion map to multiple line within source code in debug info) , how do I decide which line is better to correspond the instrucion with

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume anything about any of those numbers? There's no column headings, the readelf documentation doesn't say anything more than "Displays the interpreted contents of the .debug_line section", and the DWARF4 specification is too convoluted to easily guess what the interpreted contents are. As far as I know, the `2082` you think might be a line number could actually be a location in a different table, or a size, or a timestamp, or almost anything else.

Comment: Note: The DWARF4 spec describes a .debug_line as part of "a byte-coded language for a state machine". It's quite possible that the information displayed by readelf is opcodes that are supposed to be executed (to generate a matrix of line number info).

Comment: Ok. Maybe the `6` at the end of the 2nd line changes the meaning of the whole line into "this is the line number where the basic block (started at offset 0x55) ends" (and `2082  0x55 6` has nothing to do with the `tot->rx_packets += rpackets;` on line 2082 at all) . In the same way maybe all the other numbers in the last column mean something (maybe `5` means "start of basic block AND start of statement" and `1` means "start of statement" and..)

Comment: thank you!  I guess I need to look up some relavent info.